# $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ if $\alpha, \beta$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $2$ and $\alpha +\beta$ is a root of a quadratic.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, roots, extension-field

> If $\alpha, \beta$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $2$ and $\alpha +\beta$ is a root of a quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, then prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.

I'm stuck at showing the above statement. I think we have to show that $\alpha$ can be written as $p+q\beta$ or vice versa. But I just can't seem to show that.

I tried something as shown below but got nowhere:

If $g(x)$ is the polynomial of $\alpha+\beta$,
$g(x)=f(x)Q(x)+R(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the polynomial of $\beta$

Ideas Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We feel like there should be some correction to the following solution. However, because a good time have past since then (a few years), we decided to write a completely rewritten answer.

---

Suppose that the numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\alpha+\beta$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ with algebraic degree $2$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.
Since $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ is the splliting field of the product of the irreducible polynomials of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, it is normal and hence, Galois. Regarding the tower $K-\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)-\mathbb{Q}$, $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ and hence the Galois group is of order $4$ and abelian.

The Galois group $G=\mathrm{G}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ has two elements, say $\sigma$ and $\tau$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$, respectively and generate $G$. Note that $\sigma$ fixed the conjugate $\overline{\alpha}$ also and since $\tau(\alpha) = \overline{\alpha}$. The similar fact holds for $\beta$.

Since $\tau \sigma \neq 1, \tau, \sigma$, we have $G = \left\{ 1,\tau, \sigma , \tau \sigma =\sigma \tau \right\}$.
Let $\eta \in G$ be such that $<\eta> = \mathrm{G} (K/\mathbb{Q}[\gamma])$. Then $\eta$ is of order two and $\eta \neq \tau$, $\eta \neq \sigma$. Hence $\eta = \sigma \tau$.
But then $\eta (\gamma) = \sigma \tau (\alpha + \beta) = \overline{\alpha} + \overline{\beta}$, so $\eta(\gamma) = \gamma$ implies $\sigma(\beta) + \tau(\alpha) = \alpha + \beta$.

Now $\tau(\gamma)$ and $\sigma(\gamma)$ are both the conjugate of $\gamma$ and $\gamma$ is of degree $2$. Hence they are same.
Therefore, from $\tau(\alpha + \beta) = \sigma(\alpha+\beta)$, we have  $\tau(\alpha)-\sigma(\beta) = \alpha - \beta$, and together with  $\sigma(\beta) + \tau(\alpha) =\alpha+\beta$, $\tau(\alpha)  = \alpha$ which is an absurdity. Hence $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q} (\beta)$이다.

---

Below is the former answer given a few years ago.

---

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ be algebraic with degree $2$ such that $\alpha +\beta$ is also algebraic of degree $2$. Suppose that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \neq \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. Then we have the following non-trivial stack of Galois extensions; $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta) \supset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha), \mathbb{Q}(\beta) \supset \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore the Galois group consists of four elements which is generated by $\sigma$, $\eta$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$, respectively. Note that applying elements of the Galois group on $\gamma=\alpha + \beta$, we have four different element, $\gamma$, $\sigma(\gamma)$, $\eta(\gamma)$, $\sigma(\eta(\gamma))$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha + \beta$ has degree four which contradicts to the fact that $\alpha+\beta$ is of degree $2$. This completes the proof.

Comment: How do you know that the Gal group consists of 4 elements?

Comment: @Jhon Doe $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$ has intermediate fields. Two successive extensions are of degree at least two.

Comment: Oh, you mean the Galois group contains the four elements $1$, $\sigma$, $\eta$, and $\sigma\eta$, but these elements are not necessarily all the elements of the group?

Comment: @seoneo To show that Gal group has 4 element don't you have to show that the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are separable?

Comment: @JhonDoe  I think in characteristic $0$, the minimal polynomials are always separable.

Comment: Oh right i completely forgot thanks

Comment: @seoneo wait how do you know that function values of $\alpha+\beta$ are distinct?

Comment: @Zvi $f(\alpha+\beta)=\alpha_1+\beta_1,\alpha+\beta,\alpha_1+\beta,\alpha+\beta_1$ We know that $\alpha+\beta \neq \alpha_1+\beta$ and $\alpha+\beta \neq \alpha+\beta_1$ but $\alpha+\beta_1$ could equal $\alpha_1+\beta$

Comment: @Jhon Doe Good point. It needs further explanation. I will consider but not right now since I'm driving. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Jhon Doe Suppose that any two of them identical. That means gamma is fixed by one of nontrivial member of the Galois group. Recall that sigma and eta has oeder two. So for instance  if eta gamma= sigma gamma, then gamma is fixed by eta sigma meaning that gamma is rational.

Comment: Thanks. I showed by contradiction the there are at least 3 different values which suffices. Suppose the example above holds then $\alpha_1+\beta_1\neq \alpha+\beta$ else $\beta_1=\beta$

Comment: 'At least three' argument also looks good.

Answer (score 9):

By the hypotheses, you have six rational numbers $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1,c_0,c_1$
such that

$$
\alpha^2+a_1 \alpha +a_0=0 \tag{1}
$$

$$
\beta^2+b_1 \beta +b_0=0 \tag{2}
$$

$$
(\alpha+\beta)^2+c_1(\alpha+\beta) +c_0=0 \tag{3}
$$

Now, (3)-(1)-(2) yields :

$$
2\alpha\beta+(c_1-a_1)\alpha+(c_1-b_1)\beta +c_0-a_0-b_0=0 \tag{4}
$$

or equivalently,

$$
\beta=\frac{-(c_1-a_1)\alpha}{2\alpha+c_1-b_1},
\alpha=\frac{-(c_1-b_1)\beta}{2\beta+c_1-a_1} \tag{5}
$$

Note that the denominators are nonzero because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have degree $2$. Clearly, (5) implies $ {\mathbb Q}(\alpha) = {\mathbb Q}(\beta)$.

Comment: This is a good solution!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative but longer approach.  Let $a(x)$, $b(x)$, and $c(x)$ be monic quadratic polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ whose roots are $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma:=\alpha+\beta$, respectively.  By the condition that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $2$, we see that $a$ and $b$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  If $c$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\alpha+\beta=\gamma$ is rational, so it is obvious that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\gamma-\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.  We now assume that $c$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Write $p(x)$ for $a(x-\beta)\ a(x-\bar{\beta})\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$, where $\bar{\beta}$ is the other root of $b(x)$.  Clearly, $p(\gamma)=0$.  So, $c$ divides $p$ because $c$ is irreducible.  Now, if $\bar{\alpha}$ is the other root of $a(x)$, then
$$p(x)=(x-\alpha-\beta)(x-\bar{\alpha}-\beta)(x-\alpha-\bar{\beta})(x-\bar{\alpha}-\bar{\beta}).$$
Hence, there are three possibilities.

Case 1: $c(x)=(x-\alpha-\beta)(x-\bar{\alpha}-\beta)=a(x-\beta)$.  Since $a$ has rational coefficients, this implies that $\beta\in\mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction.

Case 2: $c(x)=(x-\alpha-\beta)(x-\alpha-\bar{\beta})=b(x-\alpha)$.  Since $b$ has rational coefficients, this implies that $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction.

Case 3: $c(x)=(x-\alpha-\beta)(x-\bar{\alpha}-\bar{\beta})$.  Therefore, we have $$\alpha\bar{\alpha}+\beta{\bar{\beta}}+(\alpha\bar{\beta}+{\bar{\alpha}}\beta)=(\alpha+\beta)(\bar{\alpha}+\bar{\beta})\in\mathbb{Q}.$$
Since $\alpha\bar\alpha$ and $\beta\bar\beta$ are rational, we get
$$\alpha\bar{\beta}+{\bar{\alpha}}\beta\in\mathbb{Q}.$$
Thus, $$\alpha(B-\beta)+(A-\alpha)\beta\in\mathbb{Q}$$
if $A=\alpha+\bar{\alpha}\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $B=\beta+\bar\beta\in\mathbb{Q}$.  So, $\alpha\beta$ is in the rational span of $1$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$.  This means $$\big[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}\big]\leq 3.$$
But $$\big[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}\big]=\big[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\big]\ \big[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}\big]=2\ \big[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\big].$$
The only even positive integer less than or equal to $3$ is $2$, so
$$2\ \big[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\big]=2$$
or
$$\big[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\big]=1.$$
This shows that $\beta\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.  Thus, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.